# How do I initialize a jQuery datepicker on a dynamically inserted <input> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form as follows:

```
<form id="my-form"></form>
```

I am using jQuery to dynamically insert an element into that form and then trying to initialize the [Pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday) datepicker on the newly inserted input tag like this:

```
$('#my-form').html('<input type="text" id="datepicker">');
var departurePicker1 = new Pikaday({
    field   : $('#datepicker')[0],
    format  : 'MMM D',
    minDate : moment().toDate()
});
```

I am able to initialize the datepicker if the input tag was available on document load. However, the nature of my app is such that the input tag gets inserted into the DOM after a user interaction. How can initialize pikaday on this dynamically inserted DOM element? Please note that I CANNOT leave this element inserted in a hidden state since it involves user interaction. It has to be initialized when the user presses a button and the input tag gets inserted into the DOM.

Comment: show us the code you have.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan I did refer to the pikaday documentation. Didn't find anything there. I see that jQuery has the .on method but I don't think it applies here.

Comment: The element present on load and the dynamic one has the same id?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan The element is not available on page load. Please see the edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You have to bind the event handler to the `body` using the `on` method.

```
$('body').on('focus',"#datepicker", function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});​
```